# Can methoxide ion be used as a base in an E1 elimination reaction?

Tags: organic-chemistry, elimination

This one problem given in my textbook is confusing because all I know is we can use a weak base for an E1 Reaction. But the reagent given is a methoxide ion. I thought the answer would B but it is C. Compound C is a result of ring expansion which is a characteristic of an E1 Reaction. I still firmly believe that the pathway should be an E2 reaction.

It's the third problem.

[image]

Comment: The agent given is not methoxide, it is methanol and heat which makes E1 far more likely.

Comment: Think about ionization to get C.

Comment: Please add a complete citation for "*my textbook*".